# How to change css option of DOM element inside the Qunit fixture?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, unit-testing, qunit

I'm creating UI interface for sudoku field. It must be a table of a **square** form with 81 cells inside (9x9). I want that width of the table would always be equal to it's height.

So I created a function that sets table's height to it's width value. Now I can call this function, for example, on window resize:

```
sudokuPresenter = {

    // other methods

    resize: function(tableId) {
        var width = $(tableId).width();
        $(tableId).height(width);
    }
};
```

I try to create unit test for resize() method using QUnit. Here is my QUnit fixture:

```
<div id="qunit-fixture">
    <table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" id="sudoku">
        <tr>
            <td><input type="text" id="input1"></td>
            <td><input type="text" id="input2"></td>
            <td><input type="text" id="input3"></td>
            <td><input type="text" id="input4"></td>
            <td><input type="text" id="input5"></td>
            <td><input type="text" id="input6"></td>
            <td><input type="text" id="input7"></td>
            <td><input type="text" id="input8"></td>
            <td><input type="text" id="input9"></td>
        </tr>
        ...
    </table>
</div>
```

And here is my test:

```
QUnit.test('Changing table\'s width', function(assert) {
    $('#sudoku').css('width', '200px');
    sudokuPresenter.resize('#sudoku');
    assert.equal($('#sudoku').height(), '200px');
});
```

The problem is that:

```
$('#sudoku').css('width', '200px');
```

doesn't work. Test shows, that the height of my table now is 1278 (the width of my monitor). So table inside the qunit fixture for unknown reason has width=1278. Firebug shows that **$('#sudoku').css('width', '200px');** didn't add any css style inside my table tag.

Is it possible at all to add CSS styles to the elements inside qunit fixture via JQuery css() method?

Comment: Could try using this alternate method: `$('#sudoku').width(200);` ?

Comment: So your qunit test is working but your presenter code is not. Correct?

Comment: I tried to use $('#sudoku').width(200); - result is the same, 
My unit test is showing wrong result, because the table inside my qunit-fixture fills the width of my monitor

Comment: when you inspect the css of qunit-fixture, you see it's placed out of view and large dimensions. You could either override with a <style></style> before the fixure or adjust in the test preparation code.